# I keep getting the error in Chrome: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden using web application Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have Windows 8 64bit. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 pro.

I created a new web application project:

> New > Project > ASP.NET Empty Web Application.

Then in the project after it was created, I right-clicked on the solution explorer:

> Add > Web Form

This is the WebForm1.aspx content:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Plugins/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/themes/Smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/newsTicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mystuff.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ul class="newsticker">
                <li>Etiam imperdiet volutpat libero eu tristique.</li>
                <li>Curabitur porttitor ante eget hendrerit adipiscing.</li>
                <li>Praesent ornare nisl lorem, ut condimentum lectus gravida ut.</li>
                <li>Nunc ultrices tortor eu massa placerat posuere.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I created a new JavaScript file:

On the solution explorer:

> Add > JavaScript File

The filename is **mystuff.js** and this is the content:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.newsticker').newsTicker();
});
```

Then on the solution explorer I did:

> Add > New Folder

The name is js.
In this folder, I added 3 js type files from my hard disk and added them as existing item.

And I dragged the file mystuff.js inside the js folder, too.

Now when I'm running my program, in most of the cases 99%, I'm getting this error on the Chrome window:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:62939/
Physical Path      D:\C-Sharp\Web\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\bout0_000\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WEBAPPLICATION1

More Information:
This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.
View more information »
```

Googled now for an hour for a solution on how to fix it, but found nothing.
Tried command prompt as admin, as someone said in one of the forums:

> 1.) Run a command prompt as Administrator.
>   2.) Copy and paste the following text “C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i”

But when I'm running this line, I'm getting the message that it can't work on this operation system. I have Windows 8 64 bit.

Then I tried this:

> 1. Open IIS (Type InetMgr)

But when I make Run and type `inaside InetMgr` I'm getting the message that it does not exist. And I never installed it before.

What else could be the problem?

EDIT**

In the Webform1.aspx i changed the html line from:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

to:

```
<html xmlns="http://localhost:*/webform1.aspx">
```

Then it worked once but then i went to the file mystuff.js and changed it from:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.newsticker').newsTicker();
    });
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.newsticker').newsTicker({
        row_height: 48,
        max_rows: 2,
        speed: 600,
        direction: 'up',
        duration: 4000,
        autostart: 1,
        pauseOnHover: 0
    });
});
```

Run the program and getting the error again in the chrome:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://localhost:62939/
Physical Path      D:\C-Sharp\Web\WebApplication1\WebApplication1
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      C:\Users\bout0_000\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WEBAPPLICATION1

More Information:
This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.
View more information »
```

Even if i change now the content in the file mystuff.js to what it was before im getting the error message in the chrome window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either name your page default.aspx

or enter the current page in your url http:   //.  localhost:*****/webform1.aspx

Comment: QBM5 tried what you suggested the second way with the url http it worked once but then next time/s im running the program again getting the error in the chrome. See my question i updated it now with what i did.

Comment: You are completely misunderstanding what I said.  The url you type into your browser needs to have /webpage.apax on the end of it, not the html namespace.  When you create a site it does not magically know what web page to display unless you name the page default.aspx, and when I added the * in the url it was because I was on a cell phone and could not copy the url provided and I didnt want to type the port you were using into the url.  I think you need to take an online course and on asp.net web pages before you build a site